Why did my teacher solved this problem this way?
The problem asks the following: which vector of the subspace $$V= \{\mathbf{x} \in \Bbb{R}^4: 2x_1+x_2+x_3+3x_4=0; 3x_1+2x_2+2x_3+x_4=0; x_1+2x_2+2x_3-9x_4=0\}$$
gives the best approximation to $(7,-4,-1,2)$.
My proffesor started by saying that: $$\mathbf{w}=(A\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{a})$$
Where $\mathbf{z}$ is the vector we are looking for and the minimum $\lVert\mathbf{w}\rVert$ will show its value. Then, he solved $\mathbf{z}$ out of the previous equation: $$(A\mathbf{z}-\mathbf{b})·A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}^T(A^TA\mathbf{z}-A^T\mathbf{z})=0$$ And from there: $$\mathbf{z}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbf{a}$$ Then he calculated the following basis of $V$: $$V=span\{\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\\-1\\0 \end{bmatrix}\}$$ And said that $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\\-1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$. From there, he used the formula he previously obtained for $\mathbf{z}$ and found out that $$\mathbf{z}=-\frac{3}{2}(0,1,-1,0)$$ My question is basically why did he use these formulas insead of calculating the projection of $\mathbf{a}$ over $V$, which I thougth it was the best approximation of a vector in a subspace.

The procedure he showed you is called the normal equations and does find the projection onto the subspace $V$ (which is the column space of $A$). Since $V$ is $1$-dimensional, you could do this more simply just by using the dot product. But you will get $A\mathbf z$ as the projection, not $\mathbf z$. Indeed, you've written $\mathbf z$, but it's really $A\mathbf z$ that you've got there as a vector of $V$. In your example, $\mathbf z$ will turn out to be a $1\times 1$ matrix. Check through all the steps.

@TedShifrin you are right! One of the things I could not see was the dimensional analysis of the problem. Thank you very much. I think I can continue from here.
